# Random crash while rendering

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm using Blender 2.75, 64 bits with two GTX-980.
I work with a script that render without issues with low resolutions (up to 480p). However, when I try to render with higher resolution the rendering process crash randomly with `Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. By randomly, I mean that sometimes it renders up to 10 images before crashing, and sometimes it crashes at the first one.
I've put two logs at the end (one successful and one failed) of the same frame being rendered at 720p.

How can I identify the source of this issue? I think that it has to do with some  performance preset, but I don't know what to look for.

Rendering successful

```
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Remaining:00:02.05 | Mem:1331.54M, Peak:1331.54M | Scene, RenderLayer | Path Tracing Tile 9/9
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Mem:1327.59M, Peak:1331.54M | Scene, RenderLayer | Finished
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Determining resolution
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Initializing execution
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 2-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 2-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 3-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 4-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 5-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 6-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) 
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 9-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 9-9
| Compositing | Tile 9-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Deinitializing execution
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Saved: D:\software\3dgenerator_blender\renderWrap\F_01_Original\Apt\lightNone\noPose\8febee5b-daa2-40de-8aac-754aeb1a486e.png
Time: 00:12.80 (Saving: 00:00.16)
```

Rendering failed

```
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Remaining:00:02.11 | Mem:1331.54M, Peak:1331.54M | Scene, RenderLayer | Path Tracing Tile 9/9
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Mem:1327.59M, Peak:1331.54M | Scene, RenderLayer | Finished
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Determining resolution
Fra:244 Mem:209.85M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Initializing execution
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 1-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 2-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 5-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) 
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) | Compositing | Tile 9-9
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) Sce:  Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) Sce:  Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) Sce:  Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Fra:244 Mem:219.73M (0.00M, Peak 404.40M) Sce:  Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I think it's a threading issue.
(AFAIK the render engines are written in C++, so it's not surprising considering threading and memory management in C++ are a PITA).

You should keep your CPU levels to below around 50% for the blender-app.exe process. 
In my case, if I bring down the threads to a max of 4, the scripts run without problems (still using all cores).
Slows it down somewhat, but at least it keeps running...

Something like this in a script file:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender
blender -b "your_blender_file.blend" -t 4 -a
pause
```

Hope it works for you.